# JScrollPane on JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jcombobox, scrollbars

I made a combobox but some of the elements are wider than the width of my box. So I tried to add a horizontal scrolpane and the only I could see is a scrolpane with a combobox inside!
Certanly something I do wrong. So here is my code without the jscrolpane.

```
    issuerdocumentJComboBox=new JComboBox<>(issuermodel);//the compo box
    issuerdocumentJComboBox.setBounds(430, 120, 100, 30);
    searchDocumentesJPanel.add(issuerdocumentJComboBox);
```

How can I add to the combobox a horizontal scrollpane?
Thank you!

Comment: In your code there is no mention of a scrollpane. What did you try exactly?

Comment: I removed it from my code since is not working! I made a scrollpane and add the combobox but then it appears a scrollpane with the combobox inside.

Comment: Well, if you add a combo to a scrollpane, that's exactly what you are supposed to get. But you want to add a scrollpane to a combo box's list component, if I understand correctly. If it's doable at all, it will probably involve some hacking.

Comment: If you thoroughly read [this OTN Discussion thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1773495), you'll find what you need. Hacking it is, alright.

Comment: Thank you!I saw this approach as I was searching for the solution but seems beyond my skills!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible!! Here's a little program I wrote to show my solution:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxEditor;

public class TestComboScroll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scroll inside Combo");
        JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox();

        combobox.addItem("");
        combobox.addItem("Item1");
        combobox.addItem("Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2 Item2");
        combobox.addItem("Item3");

        combobox.setEditor(new MyEditor());
        combobox.setEditable(true);

        combobox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
        frame.add(combobox);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class MyEditor extends BasicComboBoxEditor{
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane();
        //NOTE: editor is a JTextField defined in BasicComboBoxEditor

        public MyEditor(){
            super();
            scroller.setViewportView(editor); 
            scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        }

        /** Return a JScrollPane containing the JTextField instead of the JTextField **/
        @Override
        public Component getEditorComponent() {
            return scroller;
        }

        /** Override to create your own JTextField. **/
        @Override
        protected JTextField createEditorComponent() {
            JTextField editor = new JTextField();
            editor.setBorder(null);
            /*editor.setEditable(false); //If you want it not to be editable */
            return editor;
        }
    }
}
```

The approach is to create a **custom ComboBoxEditor that displays the JTextField editor in a scroll pane** (easier to just extend BasicComboBoxEditor). 
The `getEditorComponent()` function is then overridden to return the scroll pane instead of the text field.

These two overidden functions are called internally when you call `combobox.setEditor(new MyEditor())` so don't worry if you can't see it being used.

Here's a **screenshot** of the program showing an element wider than combobox:
[image: screenshot]

GOODLUCK!! :-)